# Where to find android official news about alternative API's?

Tags: android, permissions, newsletter

Hello friends
 In my app i had to auto-read OTP, for this i were using READ_SMS and RECEIVE_SMS permissions, but while uploading that APK to the Play Store they given error beacause of these newly added permissions and given alternative API for auto-reading the OTP.
 Now my concern is, how would i get to know that this type of news from the google, so that i should not follow the wrong coding standard.
I went through the offcial **developer.android** site but i did not find any post or news that saying one should not use READ_SMS and RECEIVE_SMS  permissions in their apps.
Please help with the link or any offical site where the google posts these type of news so that i can have look before integrating new permissions or API's into APP.

Thanks in advance
Cheers

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303?hl=en

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel Thanks for the comment, but i need news for all of the changes like, if google announces that Camera2 API is deprecated, i expect these type of announcements should be listed somewhere.

Comment: they have mailed you a long time ago. if your app uploaded before this deprecation.

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel but my play store APK does not contain this code to accept permissions.They will only mail me if my existing play store app uses those permissions.

Comment: check your manifest file.